# Compressing georeferenced images

Tags: qgis, r, georeferencing, compression

I have a bunch of georeferenced TIFF images created in QGIS. The person creating them saved them as uncompressed (around 1 GB each). 
I would like to compress them as LZW to save space.

How can I do that in a programmatic way (e.g. batch)?

I am open to QGIS or R approches. Please consider I do not know how Georeferencing information are attached to an image (e.g. I have seen somewhere references to a world file, but I do not know what it is).

Comment: TIFF files can be georeferenced in one of two ways: (1) Georeferencing information is embedded in the TIFF file as part of the metadata, so you only have one file, with the extension .tif or .tiff. (2) Georeferencing information is written in a second, ("sidecar") file with the extension .tfw, alongside the TIFF file. If you want more information about how georeferencing info is attached to a tiff file, read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the command line tool `gdal_translate`. This is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OSs (you don't state your OS).

Running:

```
gdalinfo none.tif
```

will show the info on the file, including the compression type and the locations:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: none.tif
Size is 204, 228
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (96.546435160745574,17.535114346013060)
Pixel Size = (0.004491576420598,-0.004491576420598)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  96.5464352,  17.5351143) ( 96d32'47.17"E, 17d32' 6.41"N)
Lower Left  (  96.5464352,  16.5110349) ( 96d32'47.17"E, 16d30'39.73"N)
Upper Right (  97.4627168,  17.5351143) ( 97d27'45.78"E, 17d32' 6.41"N)
Lower Right (  97.4627168,  16.5110349) ( 97d27'45.78"E, 16d30'39.73"N)
Center      (  97.0045760,  17.0230746) ( 97d 0'16.47"E, 17d 1'23.07"N)
[etc]
```

it doesn't mention a compression type, because it doesn't have one. If your GeoTIFFs aren't compressed they should also not say anything. Note the spatial information is stored in geoTIFF chunks and is output as a bounding box corner set. Great.

Let's compress it. Uncompressed file is 4.7Mb:

```
$ ls -hs none.tif 
4.7M none.tif
```

Run this:

```
$ gdal_translate none.tif lzw.tif -co COMPRESS=LZW
Input file size is 204, 228
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

and get

```
$ ls -hs lzw.tif 
1.6M lzw.tif
```

1.6Mbytes in LZW compressed form. Again `gdalinfo` shows:

```
$ gdalinfo lzw.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: lzw.tif
Size is 204, 228
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (96.546435160745574,17.535114346013060)
Pixel Size = (0.004491576420598,-0.004491576420598)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
[etc]
```

Note the `COMPRESSION=LZW` message.

Loop over your files using your command line interpreter loop functions.

You might also be able to do this via the `gdalUtils` package in R which will run these command line commands via a shell.

Indeed for my test file:

```
library(gdalUtils)
gdal_translate(
  src_dataset="none.tif",
  dst_dataset="lzwR.tif",
  co="COMPRESS=LZW")
```

results in a byte-for-byte identical output file.

Comment: some other -co to consider and offers additional compression (lossless) are `-mo "INTERLEAVE=PIXEL" -co "INTERLEAVE=PIXEL" -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "PREDICTOR=2"`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Spacedman's answer, you can set up a loop in R to compress tiffs using LZW with the `writeRaster` function in the raster package, which still uses GDAL. The `options` argument allows you to apply LZW compression.

In this example, the file is not overwritten but rather has an "_LZW" appended to the original name. To just overwrite the original file you can omit the `paste0` function in `writeRaster` and just use the file iterator (ie., `rfiles[i]`). You could also paste a directory path into the file name to aim the compressed files to a different directory. If the tif files are multi-band then you would use `stack` rather than `raster` to read the data.

```
library(raster)
setwd("C:/...")
rfiles <- list.files(getwd(), "tif$")
  for(i in 1:length(rfiles)) {
    r <- raster::raster(rfiles[i])
    raster::writeRaster(r, paste0(gsub(pattern = "\\.tif$", "", 
                        rfiles[i]), "_LZW", ".tif"), overwrite=TRUE,  
                        options="COMPRESS=LZW")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey Evans and @Spacedman. Just for clarity. I assume that an image georeferenced in qgis and saved as .tif is a geoTif. is this correct? if not... will the solutions you both proposed work anyway?

Comment: I'd be concerned that this would read in the entire +1Gb files. Might not be too efficient. The GDAL command line routines are pretty well optimised.

Comment: A "geoTIFF" is a TIFF with special metadata blocks in it that give it a spatial reference. Rasters saved from QGIS should have this data and so be valid geoTIFFs - check with the `gdalinfo` command line or `gdalUtils` package.